# how to add a column with different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a question regarding adding a column table with different type of values:
e.g. the length of the table is 10 rows. The first be given 1 of January, second row 1 of February, 3 row -1 of march etc.

Is there a function that enables this instead of writing everything "by hand".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well i just want to add that type of column, so i guess it would be a string.

Comment: Can you add an example of your current data set, and what you want the end result to look like?  [Here's some guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I guess i was unclear with my question. What i mean is let say one column of 10 rows contains values, i want to add additional column with units, however the differ from each other, so first 3 rows has the unit of "kWh" and the rest of the Rows have "MWh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need helper `DataFrame` and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) column to original.

*Notice:*
`index` of `df` is default, it means unique, monotonic (`0,1,2...`)

```
#create date range longer as max length of original df
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'rng': pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=1000)})
#convert to string and remove trailing 0
df1['new'] = df1['rng'].dt.strftime('%d of %B').str.lstrip('0')
#extract year, month, days
df1 = df1.assign(year=df1['rng'].dt.year,month=df1['rng'].dt.month, day=df1['rng'].dt.day)
#sorting and create default index (0,1,2)
df1 = df1.sort_values(['year','day','month']).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df1.head())
         rng            new  day  month  year
0 2016-01-01   1 of January    1      1  2016
1 2016-02-01  1 of February    1      2  2016
2 2016-03-01     1 of March    1      3  2016
3 2016-04-01     1 of April    1      4  2016
4 2016-05-01       1 of May    1      5  2016

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})

df = df.join(df1['new'])
print(df)
   A  B            new
0  a  4   1 of January
1  b  5  1 of February
2  c  4     1 of March
3  d  5     1 of April
4  e  5       1 of May
5  f  4      1 of June
```